# How to get last clicked radio value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sum or subtract price into total price as you can see in below working script. Following script is working properly but I want to minus previous clicked radio price from total price.

Suppose If i clicked on `Wrap` which price is 3 so total price become 8. But when i clicked on any other radio button the `Wrap` price should minus from total. For that task i tried a lot and looking for solution. Is there any way to store previous clicked price? I would like to thanks if someone guide me.

```js
$('.SECOND_POP_PRICE').on('click', function() {

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var PRICE_Product_ID = $(this).parent().attr('data-product_id');
    var SECOND_SECTION_PRICE = parseFloat($(this).parent().attr('data-second_section_price'));
    var SECOND_SECTION_POP_PRICE = parseFloat($('#pop_price_' + PRICE_Product_ID).text());
    if (SECOND_SECTION_PRICE != 0) {
      var SECOND_SECTION_UPDATED_PRICE = +SECOND_SECTION_PRICE + +SECOND_SECTION_POP_PRICE;
      $('#pop_price_' + PRICE_Product_ID).text(SECOND_SECTION_UPDATED_PRICE);
    }
  } // if checkbox is checked
  /* if($(this).prop('checked')==false){  */
  else {
    var PRICE_Product_ID = $(this).parent().attr('data-product_id');
    var SECOND_SECTION_PRICE = parseFloat($(this).parent().attr('data-second_section_price'));
    var SECOND_SECTION_POP_PRICE = parseFloat($('#pop_price_' + PRICE_Product_ID).text());
    if (SECOND_SECTION_PRICE != 0) {
      var SECOND_SECTION_UPDATED_PRICE = parseFloat(SECOND_SECTION_POP_PRICE - SECOND_SECTION_PRICE);
      $('#pop_price_' + PRICE_Product_ID).text(SECOND_SECTION_UPDATED_PRICE);
    }
  } // if checkbox is un-checked
}); /* END PRICE OF SECOND SECTION 1 */
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<small class="pop_price"><span id="pop_price_2">5</span> AED</small>
<br />
<label data-product_id="2" data-second_section_price="3.00">
<input type="radio" class=" toggle_section_3 SECOND_POP_PRICE" name="section_two" value="Wrap">
Wrap (3.00 AED)</label>
<label data-product_id="2" data-second_section_price="4.00">
<input type="radio" class=" toggle_section_3 SECOND_POP_PRICE" name="section_two" value="Roll">
Roll (4.00 AED)</label>
<label data-product_id="2" data-second_section_price="5.00">
<input type="radio" class="hide_section_3 toggle_section_3 SECOND_POP_PRICE" name="section_two" value="Open">
Open (5.00 AED)</label>
```

Comment: Save the price in a global variable, and subtract it the next time.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your guideline. Can you give an example, I will be thankful

Comment: BTW, why do you put the price in the label instead of the radio button itself?

Comment: The `if($(this).is(":checked")` is unnecessary. When you click on a radio button, it will always be checked.

Comment: @Barmar this is just example script, the real code is very complex. There are lot of data attributes. So that's why I put on label

Comment: I would suggest you to listen for `change` event instead of `click`

Comment: @Satpal I appreciate your guideline. Can you kindly give an example. Thank You

Comment: so you need find out the context on which you can attach the last radio value

Comment: use `$('.SECOND_POP_PRICE').on('change', function() {` instead of using `$('.SECOND_POP_PRICE').on('click', function() {`

Comment: use `var PRICE_Product_ID = $(this).parent().data('product_id');` instead of `var PRICE_Product_ID = $(this).parent().attr('data-product_id');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the clicked radio button to the total. Add it to the base price, which is stored somewhere other than the text of the span that you display the total in. In my code below I put it in the `data-price` attribute of the span.

There's also no need for the `if`, since you can't uncheck a radio button.

```js
$('.SECOND_POP_PRICE').on('click', function() {

  var PRICE_Product_ID = $(this).parent().attr('data-product_id');
  var SECOND_SECTION_PRICE = parseFloat($(this).parent().attr('data-second_section_price'));
  var SECOND_SECTION_POP_PRICE = parseFloat($('#pop_price_' + PRICE_Product_ID).data("price"));
  if (SECOND_SECTION_PRICE != 0) {
    var SECOND_SECTION_UPDATED_PRICE = +SECOND_SECTION_PRICE + +SECOND_SECTION_POP_PRICE;
    $('#pop_price_' + PRICE_Product_ID).text(SECOND_SECTION_UPDATED_PRICE);
  }
}); /* END PRICE OF SECOND SECTION 1 */
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<small class="pop_price"><span id="pop_price_2" data-price="5.00">5</span> AED</small>
<br />
<label data-product_id="2" data-second_section_price="3.00">
<input type="radio" class=" toggle_section_3 SECOND_POP_PRICE" name="section_two" value="Wrap">
Wrap (3.00 AED)</label>
<label data-product_id="2" data-second_section_price="4.00">
<input type="radio" class=" toggle_section_3 SECOND_POP_PRICE" name="section_two" value="Roll">
Roll (4.00 AED)</label>
<label data-product_id="2" data-second_section_price="5.00">
<input type="radio" class="hide_section_3 toggle_section_3 SECOND_POP_PRICE" name="section_two" value="Open">
Open (5.00 AED)</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// here that refers to the context which is you can use to store the last value, you need to find out that context
$('.SECOND_POP_PRICE').on('change',function(event,that){
  var updatedValue = that.lastValue - this.value;
  $('#pop_price_'+PRICE_Product_ID).text(updatedValue);
  that.lastValue = updatedValue
 })
```